# How do I tell if a network directory is empty, or just loading in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, finder

Basically, I keep a lot of files on the network.

In (at least) 10.8, there was a little spinner indicator that the directory contents were still loading, that tells you that something is happening.

This has (?) apparently been removed in 10.10, so now when I browse to a directory with ~3K+ items in it, finder just sits for 30 seconds - 1 minute with absolutely no indication that *anything* is still happening, before suddenly displaying the contents.

How can I get some sort of activity indicator back?

---

Before someone asks, the *exact same* directory takes only ~1-3 seconds to load on windows **or** linux, so it's already kind of ridiculous.

Yes, this is using SMB.

Comment: Do you mean the spinning indicator in the status bar (bottom left of the finder)? It can be shown with `cmd`+`/`